# How to get the response header of a HttpClient.Post request in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am using angular 7 and i need to get "Response Header" from the given API in service file without using "subscribe". please help me in this

i have tried by using many google answers but none of them worked.I am not able use subscribe in service.ts file because i am getting error in component.ts file as we can t use subscribe two times

```
login(email: string, password: string ) {
this.email = email;
this.password = password;


return this.http.post<any>(`this.url/auth/login`, { email, password})
.pipe(map(user => {
var currentuser:any = { user: user.user, token: user.token};
if (currentuser && user.token) {
localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(currentuser));
this.currentUserSubject.next(currentuser);
 }
return user;
 }));
```

}

Expected result :

need to get ""response header for the above api ..
**Note** : "Response header" means -- content length , token ,Content-Type , Etag, etcc

Actual result :

I am getting only the body for this not headers

Comment: What’s your need for response-headers? It seems you’re mapping the response, before trying to get the headers.

Comment: Maybe this tutorial for interceptors can help you: [Interception in Angular 7](https://www.google.at/amp/s/scotch.io/@vigneshsithirai/angular-6-7-http-client-interceptor-with-error-handling/amp)

Comment: i need to get token from headers so was trying to get but could not.Please help

Answer (score 10):

My understanding is you would like :

- to send `post` request and retrieve data
- but also have access to headers of server response.

If that's true, you should consider to invoke `HttpClient.post()` with `httpOptions = { observe: 'response' }`.
With this, `HttpClient.post()` will return an `Observable` of typed `HttpResponse` rather than just the JSON data.

Recommended read on [Angular Official docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

Your code should looks like :

```
this.http.post<HttpResponse<User>>(`${this.url}/auth/login`, { email, password }, 
  { observe: 'response' }).subscribe(response => {

  ...
  response.headers.keys(); // all header names
  ...
  response.body // response content
  ...

});
```

**UPDATED**

or inside a `service method`, which will retrieve a `User` model only, but will do something with response details, for instance: (may have typos)

```
getUserFromLogin(email: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
  return this.http.post<HttpResponse<User>>(`${this.url}/auth/login`, 
    { email, password }, { observe: 'response' }).pipe(
      map(response => {

        ...
        response.headers.keys(); // all header names
        ...
        response.body // response content
        ...

        return response.body;
      })
  )
)
```

Comment: Hi Therry Falvo,
We can get result on this and thankyou for your answer.
But i could not use subscribe here is service.ts file as its throwing error in component.ts file when i call this method api.Please suggest me some other way

Comment: Apply the same approach inside a `map` operator, and return only the `body` for instance. I updated my answer to give you an example.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed  !!

Comment: Any idea for array buffer?